# Mimic standard button in custom button

Tags: custom-button

I have a problem that the "Add to Campaign" button does not show up in the service console. So I want to create a custom button that does exactly the same as the standard button. Is there a quick way of doing this?

Tia.

Comment: Is it not showing up for a specific user/ profile or is it not showing up for the admin?

Comment: It's not showing up in the console at all, but it's showing up for all profiles in the normal salesforce app